# Why does C++17 character class [:blank:] match newlines and carriage returns?

Tags: regex, visual-c++

When working with the POSIX character class `[:blank:]` in Visual Studio 2015, I would expect newlines and carriage returns to not match but that's not the behavior I'm seeing.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/ indicates that the POSIX character class `[:blank:]` is the equivalent of `isblank` but they aren't lining up. `isblank` returns positive for space and tab, but false for carriage return and newline whereas `[:blank:]` is matching space, tab, newline, and carriage return.

Here's my sample code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool reMatches( const regex &re, const char c )
{
    return regex_search( string( 1, c ), re );
}

bool isBlank( const char c )
{
    return isblank( c ) != 0;
}

int main() {
    const char testChars[] = { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '.' };
    const char *dispChars[] = { " ", "\\t", "\\r", "\\n", "." };
    regex explicitClass( "[ \t]" );
    regex posixClass( "[[:blank:]]" );

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof( testChars ); ++i )
    {
        char c = testChars[i];
        if ( isBlank( c ) != reMatches( explicitClass, c ) )
            cout << "Mismatch found between isblank & [ \t] for " << dispChars[i] << std::endl;
        if ( isBlank( c ) != reMatches( posixClass, c ) )
            cout << "Mismatch found between isblank & [[:blank:]] for " << dispChars[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the resulting output:

```
Mismatch found between isblank & [[:blank:]] for \r
Mismatch found between isblank & [[:blank:]] for \n
```

`[ \t]` acts as expected, but `[[:blank:]]` matches `\r` and `\n`! Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's a bug in VC++. Running this code under clang or gcc exhibits the proper behavior (no output).

Code Tested: http://rextester.com/MCP44517 
Bug Submitted: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3131111/std-regex-posix-character-class-blank-matches-newlines